# Salesforce Marketing Cloud FTP bandwidth

Tags: marketing-cloud, ftp, sftp

Does Salesforce Marketing Cloud place a low bandwidth limit on their FTP server?

I'm in the Sydney region and when I try to upload a file to Salesforce Marketing Cloud's FTP site: ftp://ftp.s6.exacttarget.com, I hit a max upload speed of around 300kB/s (2.4Mbps). Abysmally slow.

I noticed that when I upload 2 files at the same time, I hit 300kB/s on both files, giving a total upload bandwidth of 600kB/s. This makes me suspect that Salesforce Marketing Cloud has configured this low bandwidth limit per FTP connection.

Can anyone confirm if this is the case or not?

Comment: all I can say is my experience with the speed has been the same as yours and my thoughts were that it is limited.

Comment: Likewise, I get the impression that bandwidth is throttled on the Enhanced FTP servers. If this is causing a challenge, have you tried zipping the files before transfer (rar's also supported though support case)? The type of files you'd be working with would compress well and you'd likely increase throughput significantly, if you're working with large files.